# Is there a way specify the host I am connecting from in scp or rsync when connected via ssh?

Tags: ssh, scp

Considering I have connected via ssh to a remote host and I want to copy a file from that remote host to my local device:

I know that I can just copy that file from a shell on the local device by using something like:

```
> scp user@remote:/path/to/file ./
```

and be done with it.

But when I am already on the remote host and I have no idea what my local IP is, is there a way to specify a copy to the local machine to the directory I was when I connected via ssh?

```
> pwd
/home/user/documents/stuff
> ssh user@remote
Connected to remote host
> scp file.txt REMOTECONNECTION
[==========] 100% Done.
> exit
> ls
file.txt
```

Comment: Can we assume that your username is the same on both systems?

Comment: No, this is usually not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is in fact possible using the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT`.

Try this:

```
scp /path/to/my_file username@$(echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'):
```

Note that this will push the file to your `home` directory.

Comment: Consider using `"${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}"` instead of the `$( ... )` part.