# Is it possible to copy a file from a remote host back to connecting host while already being connected to remote host over ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

I'm connected to a remote host over ssh. To copy something from the remote host to my local host I can copy it using scp.

However this would require typing in the complete path to the file on the remote host. I'm already in the directory to the file on my ssh connection. Does there exists a way to copy the file back to my connecting host (so my local machine) using my current open connection on the remote host?

I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546154/352890) answer already. However this requires a routable IP for the connecting host. I don't have that.

Comment: Is there something that stops you from running `scp` from the same host you're connected from? That would even allow you to use connection sharing (using the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` `ssh` options, with no need to authenticate again). Or do you absolutely need the connection to be in the other direction?

Comment: @Kusalananda I found the connection sharing stuff already and it works great. It would just be nice to send a file back using the remote session instead of opening a new terminal (or switching to one) and filling in all the information for the remote when there is an existing context with much of the info already

Comment: Was my answer here at all useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy a file back to local system with ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/copy-a-file-back-to-local-system-with-ssh)

Answer (score 1):

> Does there exists a way to copy the file back to my connecting host (so my local machine) using my current open connection on the remote host?

Sure! But we need to dip our toes into the ancient world of serial line connectivity...back when the only thing between you and a remote computer was a copper line, and "ip addresses" weren't a thing that existed (for most people), so there weren't any options for establishing some sort of out-of-band connection to a remote host.

Many of the tools we used back then survived into the modern era, and along the way picked up various networking tricks now that serial connectivity wasn't the only option...but they kept the rest of their feature set, including support for "inline" file transfer protocols (that is, transfer protocols that run over your existing connection, rather than opening a new connection).

Here are two solutions that will do what you want; in both cases you'll need to install software on the local **and** remote hosts.

### Using Kermit

1. Install [kermit](https://www.kermitproject.org/current.html) on both the local and the remote hosts.
2. Use `kermit` to establish the ssh connection to the remote host:

   ```
   kermit -EC 'ssh remotehost.example.com'
   ```
3. Use `kermit` on the remote host to start a file transfer:

   ```
   remotehost$ kermit -s somefile.txt
   ```
4. Watch your local Kermit automatically enter receive mode and receive the file. You'll see it show up in your local current working directory.

### Using screen + lrzsz

You can do something similar using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and the [lrzsz](https://www.ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) package, which includes a [Zmodem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) implementation.

1. Install `screen` locally.
2. Install `lrzsz` both locally and on the remote host.
3. Edit your `~/.screenrc` to include:

   ```
   zmodem catch
   ```
4. Start a new `screen` session and connect to the remote host:

   ```
   screen -e '' ssh remotehost.example.com
   ```
5. Use the `sz` command to transfer a file:

   ```
   remotehost$ sz somefile.txt
   ```

   This will bring up an `rz` command at the bottom of the screen, just press `<return>`.
6. Watch the file transfer to your local system. As before, you'll find the file in your local current working directory.

### Using zssh + lrzsz

[Zssh](https://zssh.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper for ssh that understand Zmodem escapes. The process looks almost exactly like the previous section, but you use `zssh` instead of screen:

1. Install `lrzsz` on both the local and remote hosts.
2. Connect to the remote host:

   ```
   localhost$ zssh remotehost
   ```
3. Initiate a file transfer:

   ```
   remotehost$ sz somefile.txt
   ```
4. Type `CTRL-SPACE` to enter file transfer mode and type `rz` (then `<return>`).

---

I'm running on Fedora 36, and everything mentioned here (kermit, screen, lrzsz, zssh) is available as a package; to get "all of the above" you would run:

```
sudo yum install screen ckermit zssh lrzsz
```

On other distributions you may need to install things manually.